# Partition By using Oracle SQL Developer tool (GUI)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been given a task to create ROW_NUMBER() in the oracle database using graphical user interface GUI.
 I am using the Oracle SQL developer tool but am unable to find any option which says 'Partition by' or 'Row_number'. I want to know if there is any option available using the graphical User interface (GUI) in the SQL developer tool.

currently, I am using:

- Oracle Database 19c
- Oracle SQL developer tool Version 21.4.1.349 Build 349.1822

Please share your expert thoughts, thanks :-)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for the sample data; the expected output; **YOUR** attempts at creating the query so far.

Comment: Why cannot you just type `SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY some_column) FROM table_name t;` into the worksheet in the GUI? Do you really have to try creating the query only using the mouse?

Comment: Yes @MT0, I am forbidden to use the command line. The challenge is to create Roll_Number using GUI only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring your comments around 'ROW_NUMBER()', here's how you can create a partitioned table using the GUI provided by SQL Developer.

Create Table dialog.

Enable the 'Advanced' view.

[image]

On Partitions page. select your partitioning scheme (here I chose 'Range'), find your column, select it, move it to the Right.

Then on Partitions page, create your first partition...when you insert a row, it has to have somewhere to go, right?

Click the + button to create one, give it a name, and give it a range of values. So in my example, I won't need a 2nd partition until I go to insert the 10,001st row.

[image]

If you want to see the DDL required to replicate what you've done with your mouse handiwork, see the DDL page.

```
CREATE TABLE SH.PART_BY_ROWNUM 
(
  ROWNUM2 INTEGER 
, DATAS BLOB 
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (ROWNUM2) 
(
  PARTITION PARTITION1 VALUES LESS THAN (10000)  
);
```